# How can I remove / clear items out of a list control in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a list control in Flex that has been data bound to an e4x xml object from an HTTPService.

I would now like to have a button that clears the list, how can I do this?

I have tried:

```
list.dataProvider = null;
```

which does not seem to work, I have also tried:

```
list.dataProvider = {};
```

which clears the items but leaves [object,object] as the first item in the list...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps...

```
list.dataProvider = new Array();
```

Answer (score 7):

Setting the `dataProvider` to a new `Array` object will throw an error:

> Implicit coercion of a value of type Array to an unrelated type
>   fl.data:DataProvider.

Instead, you should use the `removeAll()` method provided by DataProvider:

```
list.dataProvider.removeAll();
```

This triggers a REMOVE_ALL event in the DataProvider which, in turn, will update your list.

Comment: -1 - Questioner is asking about Flex, whereas your answer only pertains to components inheriting from [fl.controls.SelectableList](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/SelectableList.html#dataProvider).  The corresponding Flex components' property `dataProvider` is of type Object, and doesn't have such casting problems as you ran into.